# Angular 8 @ViewChild translation

Tags: angular, angular8

I have some code that works on angular 7 but not angular 8.

It's basically this:

```
@ViewChild(ChildComponent) child;
```

How can I make this code work on Angular 8 as I know it's been changed.

What do I have to do to the code above?

Here is the full code:

```
import { Component, ViewChild, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ChildComponent } from "../child/child.component";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  template: `
    Message: {{ message }}
    <app-child></app-child>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./parent.component.css']
})
export class ParentComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  @ViewChild(ChildComponent) child;

  constructor() { }

  message:string;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.message = this.child.message
  }
}
```

Comment: If you upgrade using the CLI it will rewrite the usages of queries so that it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I **quote** the following from [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/30291)

The reason that your example doesn't work is that you're trying to access the results of a ViewChild query before the view has completed initializing. This is why your code should be placed in the ngAfterViewInit hook (after view inits) and not the ngOnInit hook (before view inits).

In Ivy, we have made the timing consistent so that both ViewChild and ViewChildren queries resolve after the view inits by default, rather than depending on the location of results in the template. It's a bit easier to reason about, though it means that you won't find view query results in ngOnInit by default.
If you need the results of a query in that hook, you can explicitly choose to label the query as "static"

So for your use case, you can either mark the query static (as the V8 schematic would do):

```
@ViewChild('test', {static: true}) test: ElementRef;
```

... or move the logic to ngAfterViewInit (preferred).

Comment: I've added full code so you can see... ngAfterViewInit won't work. I get: error TS2554: Expected 2 arguments, but got 1.

Comment: Try the second option as mentioned above

Comment: I don't understand how to change it :/

Comment: Try ``@ViewChild(ChildComponent, {static: true}) child;``